# How do we dynamically change the axis labels in Microsoft Excel 2010 depending upon the unit chosen for corresponding values?

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, excel-2010, axis-labels

Let's say I have a chart in Excel where the x-axis has months in the last one year and y-axis has sales in either dollars or euros.
Is there a way using which we can have the y-axis labels contain the corresponding currency symbol ($ or €) depending upon how the sales values have been indicated in the data?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit (changing labels)**
Axis labels pick up their formatting automatically from the underlying data by default.  You can rely on this and simply change the formatting of the data and let it propagate.  Alternatively, you can change the "Number" formatting on the axis label and force a given format (symbol) regardless of the underlying data.

**Automatic (set on the data)**  If you want to go back to automatic after making manual changes, check the box in the Number section called "Linked to source".
[image: automatic label formatting]

**Override** (note that the y-data is euros but the axis label is dollar as set in the formatting menu)
[image: forced label formatting]

**Original (changing axis titles)**

Axis titles can be set up using formulas.  It is not entirely obvious, but if you select the axis label, you can type a formula in the formula bar.  The easiest one is to set the formula equal to a cell where you do the logic and generate text with the $ or euro symbol.

Note in the example below I am generating the label based on the symbol in cell E2.  You could generate the text based on the data or whatever method you want.  The formula in the formula bar applies to the y-axis label.

The formula in cell E3 is `="SALES " & E2`.

**dollar example**
[image: axis label example]

**euro example**
[image: axis with label changed]

Comment: Thanks, Byron. I appreciate your response. I was referring to the Axis labels in my question and not the title; as in, the values 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on that you have on each of your axes. Please let me know if you can help me there.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma, Oh.  Those get picked up automatically from the formatting on the values.  You can either set the formatting on the data and let it go automatically, or change the "Number" formatting for either axis and force a certain value.  I will edit the answer.